# How to extract integer value in sentence in java

Tags: java

I need to extract integer values in string.

For example

`this is the java 1234 and 7899/45767 program`

in that I need to extract only integer like

```
1234
7899
45767
```

Comment: Where is the code actually ? :)

Comment: Use StringTokenizer and String.indexOf and String.substring methods

Comment: Or for example regexp

Comment: Homework? Show your efforts first.

Comment: One of the worst questions ever. Not only does is not show any own effort, or code, it does not even try to show what OP tries to achieve in an understandable way

Answer (score 2):

I think a regex could fit your need:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

String aParser="123 bla bla 1234 bla bla 0324";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(\d+)");
Matcher m=p.matcher(aParser);

while(m.find())
{ 
   //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Scanner.nextInt()` method

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner("this is the java 1234 and 7899/45767 program, in that i need to extract only integer like 1234 7899 45767");
while(sc.hasNext()) {
   boolean scanned = false;
   if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
      scanned = true;
   }
   if(!scanned)
     sc.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+").matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```